# Command works in powershell but not via system()/system2()/shell()?

Tags: r, powershell

I'm looking to run a powershell command from R. it works in powershell, but I can't get it working in R.

This works in powershell

```
[guid]::NewGuid()
```

But none of these work from R

```
system("[guid]::NewGuid()", intern=TRUE)
system2("[guid]::NewGuid()")
shell("[guid]::NewGuid()")
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to tell `system()` that you want to use `powershell` and not `cmd` as executable.

Assuming powershell is in you PATH variable try

```
system('powershell -command "[guid]::NewGuid()"', intern=TRUE)
```

You can also try leaving `intern=TRUE` away depending what kind of output you expect.